# How to check if a file exists or not and create/delete if does/does not exist in shell

Tags: bash, shell

In shell, I want to check if a file exists or not then create if it doesn't exist or delete if it exists. For this I need a one liner and am trying to do something like:

```
ls | awk '\filename\' <if exist delete else create>
```

I need the `ls` as my problem has some command that outputs a list of strings that need to be pipelined to `awk` then possibly `touch/mkdir`.

Comment: `[ -f file ] && rm rile || touch file`?

Comment: can you type out the whole syntax please? it looks promising till now.

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Good to know that Cyrus. But I actually have `oc projects` instead of `ls`. I just wanted to make it simpler. And instead of `touch` i need to do `oc new-project <project-name>`.

Comment: That is just shorthand for `if [ -f "$file" ]; then rm "$file"; else touch "$file"; fi` Both statements will do the same thing. With the name of the file you are checking in the variable `$file` (or any name you like) the conditional expression with `-f` tests `"True if file exists and is a regular file"` See [man 1 bash](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) under the heading `Conditional Expressions`.

Comment: And just mildly better: `[ -f file ] && rm -- file || touch -- file` which covers funny filenames starting with a hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ] || [ ! -f  "$1" ] # $1 is input filename and -f check if $1 is a regular file
then
    rm "$1" #delete the file
else
   touch "$1" #create the file
fi
```

save the file as filecreator.sh

change the permission to allow execution with `sudo chmod a+rx`

while running the script use `./filecreator.sh yourfile.extension`

You can see the file in your directory.

Answer (score 0):

Using `oc projects` and `oc new-project` instad of `ls` and `touch` as indicated in a comment.

```sh
oc projects |
while read -r proj; do
    if [ -d "$proj" ]; then
        rm -rf "$proj"
    else
        oc new-project "$proj"
    fi
done
```

I don't think there is a useful way to write this as a one-liner. If you like, you can replace the newlines with semicolons, except after `then` and `else`.

You really should put your actual requirements in the question itself. `ls` is a superbly useless example because it cannot list a file which doesn't already exist, and [you should not use `ls` in scripts at all.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 0):

```
rm yourfile 2>/dev/null || touch yourfile
```

If the file existed before, `rm` will succeed and erase the file, and the `touch` won't be executed. You end up with no file afterwards.

If the file did not exist before, `rm` will fail (but the error message is not visible, since it is directed to the bitbucket), and due to the non-zero exit code of `rm`, the `touch` will be executed. You end up with an empty file afterwards.

Caveat: If the file exists, but you don't have permissions to remove it, you **won't notice this error**, due to the redirection of stderr. Hence, for debugging and later diagnosis, it might be better to redirect stderr to some file instead.